# How to assign NaN to values j < k in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, nan

I'm a Matlab newbie and I would like to assign NaN values to an array of size(j, k, l) wherever the dimension is j < k or j < l. How do I do this most efficiently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `bsxfun` to do it efficiently:

```
J = (1:size(A,1)).';
K = 1:size(A,2);
L = reshape(1:size(A,3),1,1,[]);
A(bsxfun(@or,bsxfun(@lt,J,K),bsxfun(@lt,J,L))) = NaN;
```

In MATLAB r2016b or Octave you can simply write:

```
J = (1:size(A,1)).';
K = 1:size(A,2);
L = reshape(1:size(A,3),1,1,[]);
A(J<K|J<L)=NaN;
```

Result of a test on a matrix `A = rand(500,400,300)`:

```
 ________________________________
| METHOD   | MEMORY   | SPEED    |
|==========|==========|==========|
| MESHGRID | 1547 MB  | 1.24 Secs|
|----------|----------|----------|
| BSXFUN   | 57 MB    | 0.18 Secs|
|__________|__________|__________|
```

Comment: @AnderBiguri Thanks, sometimes chance is helpful :).

Answer (score 3):

Use fancy vecotization:

```
% this may be memory expensive for big matrices:
[j,k,l]=meshgrid(1:size(A,1),1:size(A,2),1:size(A,3));

% Tada!
A(j<k | k<l)=NaN;
```

---

If you do not have enough RAM (or do not want to use it for this), then the best option is just loopy:

```
for jj=1:size(A,1)
   for k=1:size(A,2)
       for l=1:size(A,3)
           if (jj<k | k<l)
               A(jj,k,l)=NaN;
           end
       end
   end
end
```

This will likely be slower, but doesn't need any extra memory.

Comment: Great, will use it! You say it is memory expensive - you recommend it over other solutions for big matrices, though?

Comment: @LenaH Updated!

Comment: Super. That's what I had. Will see if my memory is enough for the fast one.

Comment: @LenaH consider accepting the answer as valid then ;)